# Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric when datatype is decimal (7,6) in SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4

I am able to solve the issue when I choose the datatype `decimal(5,2)`.

Datatype in all the column is `decimal(7,6)` in SQL Server.

Model class

```
 public double SM1 { get; set; }
 public double SM2 { get; set; }
 public double SM3 { get; set; }
 public double SM4 { get; set; }
```

Server Side Casting done and tried to convert to decimal is also not working  since I am trying to update a record. And I am getting error as follow :

> Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric

Server side code

```
 int UpdateSaveProductMargin = cls.fncSaveProductMargin(
                             Convert.ToDecimal(viewModel.SM1),
                             Convert.ToDecimal(viewModel.SM2),
                             Convert.ToDecimal(viewModel.SM3),
                             Convert.ToDecimal(viewModel.SM4));
```

I can't change the database table datatype since multiple application is connected to the same datatype.

If I change the datatype in server-side code to decimal

Model class if update

```
 public decimal SM1 { get; set; }
 public decimal SM2 { get; set; }
 public decimal SM3 { get; set; }
 public decimal SM4 { get; set; }
```

Then my `ModelState.IsValid` returns false and It doesn't go into chunk where update code is written.

So I need to update the update query for the record which can covert `decimal(7,6)` to `decimal(5,2)` or cast the same in C#.

Comment: ConvertToDecimal is only need if the return type is a string.  If the return type is a number you do not need to convert.

Comment: what should I do then? Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: What are some of the values you're trying to convert? `decimal(7,6)` only gives you a range of `-9.999999` through `+9.999999`.

Comment: For e.g. 10 , 20 , 30 , 40 .. or If I enter 511321.3223 than also it return me the same error.

Comment: C# has three types capable of holding values with decimals, `float`, `double` and `decimal`.  The `decimal` type is exact, while float and double are approximations, capable of wider range of values at the cost of some inexactitude.  SQL's `DECIMAL` type includes precision and scale attributes that describe how many total digits and how many digits to the right of the decimal point the column can hold.  As @AlwaysLearning points out, `decimal(7,6)` can only hold numbers in a very small range.  Your error is likely the result of trying to convert something outside that range to a SQL decimal

Comment: Do not convert.  It is not needed if the object you are writing is already a number.  If the input  is a string the number may be in a different culture where the decimal point is a comma and your default culture is using a period.

Comment: @ShanuGarg: right.  If you enter 0 or 3.14152, it will work.  But 10, 20, 30, 40 or 511321.3223 are all outside the range of `decimal(7,6)` (which only has a range of `-9.999999` through `+9.999999`).  They will all fail

Comment: Well, `10` is larger than `9.999999` so no, it won't fit in a `decimal(7,6)` @ShanuGarg . `(7,6)` means you want to store 7 digits of precision, with 6 of them being the scale (the numbers after the decimal point). That means you have enough space for **one** significant digit, and `10.000000` has 2.